# Ressources for learning software design using uml

Tags: uml, software-design

I would some ressources for learning software design using uml (Case study, books)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best source for learning UML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536648/what-is-the-best-source-for-learning-uml)

Comment: @Gert G : As duffymo said from your link "knowing UML syntax well is not the same thing as knowing how to design". Read again my question.

Answer (score 2):

I´d recommend the book "applying UML and patterns" from Craig Larman. It teaches how to specify and design a software system using UML as notation

Answer (score 2):

I am currently reading:

> Object-oriented Systems analysis and design using UML

By Bennett

Added to the initial understanding i gained from Fowler's UML Distilled.

Answer (score 1):

["UML distilled"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) by [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/) is a very good introduction to UML.